# Message is consumed twice

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

There is a topic with 8 partitions in a Kafka cluster. 
I implemented application to consume the topic with KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter which concurrent is 8 and offsetManager is KafkaTopicOffsetManager.
When I start one application instance everything is right. But when I start two application instances, I find the meesge is consumed twice. Do you know why and how to solve it? I need change to highLevelConsumer?

Answer (score 1):

You have to distribute the partitions across instances with that adapter.

We are working on upgrading to kafka 0.9 java clients which supports consumer groups.

[The first milestone for the core project is available](https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/14/spring-for-apache-kafka-milestone-1-available).

We need to work on releasing a milestone of spring-integration-kafka 2.0 that uses this new client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, looking forward to spring-integration-kafka 2.0 release.